# How to load dynatree properly to select more or deselect nodes

Tags: php, jquery, json, edit, dynatree

What about generate tree with selected values? What i do is storing the selected keys, and then on edit, i generate the tree with the help of an extra json array with the selected keys. But the problem is if i change the order of the images via mysql, the keys does not stand for the real values.

This is how i create the json array for a tree, with depth = 1.

```
    /*** get image tree structure ***/
    $i = 0; $j = 0;//$j = 0;  $l = 0;
    $counter = 0;
    $whole_tree = $this->cms_model->get_tree_big_array('0');
    foreach ($whole_tree as $node_key => $node_array) {
        foreach ($node_array as $key_name => $node_element_value) {

            if($key_name == 'title'):
                $new_array[$i][$key_name] = $node_element_value;                
            elseif($key_name == 'filename'):
                $new_array[$i][$key_name] = $node_element_value;
            elseif($key_name == 'id'):
                $new_array[$i][$key_name] = $node_element_value;
            elseif($key_name == 'is_folder'):
                $new_key_name = 'isFolder';

                if($node_element_value == '1'):
                    $new_node_element_value = 'true';
                    $new_array[$i][$new_key_name] = $new_node_element_value;

                    $cur_id = $node_array['id'];
                    $children = $this->cms_model->get_children_array($cur_id);

                    foreach ($children as $child_key_name => $child_element_value) {
                        foreach ($child_element_value as $super_child_key_name => $childnode_element_value) {

                        if($super_child_key_name == 'title'):
                            $new_array[$i]['children'][$child_key_name][$super_child_key_name] = $childnode_element_value;
                        elseif($super_child_key_name == 'filename'):
                            $new_array[$i]['children'][$child_key_name][$super_child_key_name] = $childnode_element_value;
                        elseif($super_child_key_name == 'id'):
                            $new_array[$i]['children'][$child_key_name][$super_child_key_name] = $childnode_element_value;
                        endif;
                        }
                        $counter++;
                    }
                else:
                    $new_node_element_value = 'false';
                endif;



                $cur_id = $node_array['id'];
                $children = $this->cms_model->get_children_array($cur_id);

            endif;
            $j++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    //print_r($new_array);
    $json_tree = json_encode($new_array);
    $data['json'] = $json_tree;
```

Above is the dynatree script, where i pick some photos for a page and make previews for what is selected and what is activated. In this case i have photos.

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("#tree").dynatree({
    checkbox: true,

    onPostInit: function(isReloading, isError){
        var data = <?php echo $json;?>; // the whole json array tree object
        var array = <?php echo $key_array;?>; // these the stored keys where selected from last post.
        var imgarray = <?php echo $img_array;?>; // these are the selected images id's

        for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            var tree = jQuery("#tree").dynatree("getTree");
            tree.getNodeByKey(array[i]).select(); // i'm selecting on load the selected nodes using this function.
            // what i want is to select the nodes using the $img_array array in order to have
            // an independence in what order the nodes are generated
        }

    },                              

    onActivate: function(node) {
        var site_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
        var controller_path = '/admin/actions/get_image_path/';
        var image_id = node.data.id;


        jQuery.ajax({
            url: site_url+controller_path+image_id,
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'html',
            processData: false,
            success: function(msg){
                jQuery('.image-previewer').css({display: 'block'});
                jQuery('.image-previewer').html(msg);
            }
        });

    },
    onSelect: function(flag, node) {
        //alert(node.data.id);
        if(flag){
            jQuery('<div id="'+node.data.id+'">').css({
                    display: 'block',
                    borderRadius: '3px',
                    margin: '0 0 10px 0',
            })
            .appendTo('.list');
            jQuery('<span id="'+node.data.id+'" style="padding:0px 5px; line-height:40px; margin-right:5px; float:left; background:#fffccc;">Εχεις επιλέξει: '+node.data.filename+' </span>').appendTo('div#'+node.data.id+'');
            jQuery('<img id="img_'+node.data.id+'" src="http://pinecone.gr/files/thumbs/'+node.data.filename+'" style="float:left; margin-right:5px">').appendTo('div#'+node.data.id+'');   
            jQuery('<span>').css({
                lineHeight: '40px',
                display: 'block',
                float: 'left',
                id: 'span_'+node.data.id
            })

            jQuery('<input>',
            { 
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'img_array[]',
                id : 'input_'+node.data.id,
                value: 'img_'+node.data.id
            }).appendTo('div#'+node.data.id+'');

            jQuery('<input>',
            { 
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'keys_array[]',
                id : 'inputkeys_'+node.data.id,
                value: node.data.key
            }).appendTo('div#'+node.data.id+'');                                        

            jQuery('<br clear="all" />').appendTo('div#'+node.data.id+'');
            jQuery('input#input_'+node.data.id+'').attr({ value: node.data.id})

        }else if(!flag){
            jQuery('.list div#'+node.data.id+'').remove();
        }

    },
    persist: false,
    children:
    <?php echo $json; ?>

});
```

});

If i change the order of the images records in database, or by adding an image, the selected keys for the current record does not stand for real, because the structure is changed, and i have data integrity failure. What do you suggest for solution.
Thanks in Advance